# Calling parent method from child component not working in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child

I am trying to call a parent method from the child component using $emit but it doesn't call the method. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Parent Component

```
<template>
 <Index></Index>
</template>

<script>
 import Index from 'views/index.vue'
 export default {
  components: {
   Index
  },
  methods: {
   reloading: function() {
    console.log("Hello");
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
 <div>
   <v-btn @click="toggleChange">Change</v-btn>
 </div>
<template>

<script>
 export default {
  methods: {
   toggleChange: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.$axios.put('status.json')
    .then(response => {
      this.$emit('reloading');
     });
   },
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for the event in your parent component and *then* call the function when it fires:

```
<Index @reloading="reloading"></Index>
```